# Heroku. Two or more applications in one dyno

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, vps

I have already bought a dyno on Heroku I use for an application in Rails.

Now I need to try 24 hours 24 hours, 7 days out of 7 days, for a whole week, another app that I made for a customer. If the customer will like it then I'll buy a dyno for the customer and there will be no problem.

But now the problem is this for me:

given the new prices and the new features of the new heroku, I can no longer have 24 hours on 24 and 7 days out of 7 a dyno always working. There are at least 6 hours of sleep each day. And I can not perform tests with this configuration.

So I wondered if you can put two different applications in my single dyno that I bought at $ 7 per month (the Hobby one).

Is that possible?

Also if I modify my Rails app.

**For example**:

- if I go to "`myapp.heroku-app.com/one`" it will start the first Rails application;
- if I go to "`myapp.heroku-app.com/second`" it will start the second Rails app.

I'm just dreaming?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many Rails apps on 1 Heroku dyno?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250771/how-many-rails-apps-on-1-heroku-dyno)

Comment: That question is for 2013. Today is different. There is a time limit on the free dyno. I'm looking for a workaround for many apps in one dyno. How to?

Comment: Just a thought: you could deploy your test app to two different apps on heroku. And route 12 hours to the one and 12 hours to the other... The router can be a seperate app again ;)

Comment: @eceeb, can you explain better?