# Rails deployment in Heroku: can we share $7/pm dyno across several applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devops

If I deploy five low traffic Rails applications to Heroku,
and I don't want any 'free dyno idling drama',
do I need to pay $7 each for 5 applications?

Or can Heroku smartly share my $7 dyno across my five applications?
(Due to the low traffic, only only application will be active at any given time)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can schedule paid dyno to share 5 applications. Paid(Hobby) dyno does have 10 worker process.

https://www.heroku.com/pricing

[How many Rails apps on 1 Heroku dyno?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250771/how-many-rails-apps-on-1-heroku-dyno)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible to share a paid dyno between apps. Each app will have it's base free dyno, along with the idling issues and you have to add the paid dynos on a per app basis.